# Send push notifications with Ionic 2 to users group in background

Tags: push-notification, background, ionic2

I want to display a push notifications in background for a defined users group.

Exemple :

- Send Push for users in "group A" = User in group A show this push
- Send Push for users in "group A" = User in group B don't show this push

In Ionic i have not seen a callback or others to filter received push by criteria (group ID for exemple)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [firebase](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/), you can use [subscribe to topic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/#subscribeToTopic).
You can also get more details in the [docs](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm)

Comment: Good ! else It's not possible with "phonegap-plugin-push" ?

Comment: A topics is public. You confirm ?

Comment: @BastienD By public do you mean send a notification to all your users? if yes then set the topic as all like 'topic/all' if you wanna send to all (android users only) then 'topic/android'